# redirect files to user domain when after user buys a domain

Tags: php, redirect, domain-driven-design

I have created a e-commerce platform. When a user buys his own domain i want him to redirect his domain, its like bigcommerce and buildabazaar kind. But i am not getting how to do it.

Please suggest me on this

Comment: Can you be more specific please. You are developing e-commerce app and after you finish it you want to sell it? The part with user redirect his domain is not clear enough also.

Comment: no not like that. There is option to build his own site and either he can go for subdomain or he can buy his own domain. after he buys it, he should get his own site from my domain. how can i do it?

Comment: To clear things up, you want that your buyer can type www.hisdomain.com and load app from your server while URL in browser stays like he is hosting the app?

Comment: exactly thats what i wanted. But i am not getting how wxactly do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This redirection must be done on your buyer domain/hosting side:

You need what is called "Masked domain foraward" and it is done at the domain registrant control panel.

Or you can do a simple frameset forward, just place this code in the index.html on the buyers domain:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>site</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="100%" scrolling="yes" border="0">
<frame src="http://www.your-e-commerce-site.com/yourbuyer_1">
</frameset>
</html>
```

- This redirect will retain buyers domain in URL but will not give you any sub urls, which means that in URL bar will always be his domain page like http://www.buyersdomain.com even if he clicks trough his app...